# Should we close a question where OP answered himself but did not accept?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, statistics

I think it would be good to minimize unanswered question. So should we close questions like [this one](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/2427/who-is-the-asian-singer-in-the-gif), where OP answered to his own question but did not accept, particularly when the question has a poor documentary interest (no googling potential)?

In many cases, the asker will never come back again... and if he answered himself, can we suppose the answer is correct?

Comment: What specific benefit would come from closing?

Comment: @topomorto Doesn't it get out off unanswered statistics?

Comment: Possibly, if it's genuinely unanswered - I honestly don't know. However if you mean the stats at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans, does that relate to questions with an *accepted* answer, or just questions with *an* answer? I assumed the latter, as e.g. korean.stackexchange.com/ has 100% answered, but not all questions have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

No. Please do not try and close questions for these reasons. A question is considered answered if there is a positive answer on the question (i.e. 1 or above) or has the answer accepted. So if there answer isn't accepted but has a positive score it is answered.

Another note: *please do not try and inflate the sites statistics.* This will not help us graduate and skew information about what we actually need to work on.

Comment: So, in my example, the "no googling potential" cause is enough to cast a close?

Comment: @Bebs no. The scope of the site should determine if the question is closed or not. There are other basic reason like too broad, primarily opinion based, and unclear, but even those come down to the scope of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Dom has answered the questions I had in the comments about the statistics, and I'd agree with his answer.

Just on the googlability thing - it's good to remember that questions on Stack Exchange sites can be found by other mechanisms than googling. There are various ways to sort and filter, and questions are linked from users' pages, in the Related questions sidebar, and may be linked from other pages both within and from outside the SE network. So just because someone wouldn't search for the answer to a particular question doesn't mean they might not come across it and find it interesting.